# View Not Adding to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to add a movie to my cell in my UITableViewCell.

The movie seems to play with sound, but no visual. I think I am having trouble adding the moviePlayer view to my cell.

Take a look at my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FeedCustomCell";
FeedCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...
cell.username.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _usernameString];
cell.createdDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _createdString];
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// First, get the URL for the video file you want to play.  For example, if you have an array of the movie file URLs, you'd do this:

FeedCustomCell *cell = [[FeedCustomCell alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_videoPathString];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
CGRect previewFrame = CGRectMake(cell.videoView.frame.origin.x, cell.videoView.frame.origin.y, cell.videoView.frame.size.width, cell.videoView.frame.size.height);
moviePlayer.view.frame = previewFrame;
moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
[cell.videoView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[cell.videoView bringSubviewToFront:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer play];

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Im not sure but I think you should add the subview then play the video not the opposite

Comment: Is cell.videoView for real? If it is nil or not in the cell's content view bounds, you won't see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually not creating **moviePlayer** in your tableview cell. Inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method you creating another ***FeedCustomCell*** and adding your ***moviePlayer*** there. You even not adding this local ***FeedCustomCell***  inside table view cell.

The easier way to fix it is replace

```
 FeedCustomCell *cell = [[FeedCustomCell alloc] init];
```

with

```
 FeedCustomCell *cell = (FeedCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're allocating a new cell with this line:

```
FeedCustomCell *cell = [[FeedCustomCell alloc] init];
```

But this cell does not exist anywhere your view hierarchy, so it will not be displayed. If you're trying to insert the movie player into the existing cell that was tapped, then you would get the cell like this:

```
FeedCustomCell *cell = (FeedCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Otherwise, if you're trying to insert a new cell, you need to do the following:

1. Add a new item in your data model to represent the new cell.
2. Insert the new row using `[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]`.
3. Dequeue and configure the inserted cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I get incopatible pointer types for cell when I try to do the cellForRowAtIndexPath line.

Comment: @AnthonyGeranio: Try explicitly casting to `FeedCustomCell`.  Replace `FeedCustomCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` with `FeedCustomCell *cell = (FeedCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` - Note the additional `(FeedCustomCell *)`.

Comment: @AnthonyGeranio Sorry I left out the cast. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
FeedCustomCell *cell = [[FeedCustomCell alloc] init];
```

in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you are creating a whole new instance of `FeedCustomCell` - what you want to do is get the cell that user clicked.  Replace that line with:

```
FeedCustomCell *cell = (FeedCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```